# No internet access when connected to network via wireless and wired connections

Tags: raspbian, networking

I have recently been unable to access the internet via my raspberry pi 2, even with a valid wireless and wired internet connection. I tried `ping` and `traceroute` to a variety of sites, with the following results. 
[image]

Comment: Check to make sure your gateway matches that of your router ip in /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: It does match. Any more help

Comment: The wired route normally takes precedence.  Is your internet gateway connected to your wired or wireless interfaces?

Comment: Try `ping 8.8.8.8`.  If you do not have DNS working, you won't be able to use domain names (`google.com`), only IP addresses.

Comment: `ping 8.8.8.8` returned `connect : Network is unreachable` as did `ping 216.58.219.195` which should be google's ip